# 3 month rolling window of monthly data to give JFM,FMA etc to OND

Tags: r

I currently have a monthly data of frequency of occurrence, I want to create a 3 month rolling window without finding the mean of the frequency; Hence, say for 
Jan 12
Feb 14
Mar 10

Feb 7
Mar 5
Apr 8

and so on till OND. I have my data from 1980-2016. The idea is to get these for all the years so I can do a PCA with some climate indices. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

With `expand.grid` we create all possible combinations of month indices and filter them so that they conform to JFM, FMA etc.
    Then for each input (JFM,FMA) we compute PCA for each subset and return datapoint of interest.

Have used time-series data from `managers` dataset of `PerformanceAnalytics` for this demo.

**Data:**

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")

data(managers)
```

**Month Indices:**

```
mthIndices=expand.grid(1:12,1:12,1:12)

#keep indices where month1 < month2 < month3
mthIndices = mthIndices[ (mthIndices$Var1 < mthIndices$Var2) & (mthIndices$Var2 < mthIndices$Var3), ]

#keep indices where   month2 - month1 = 1 month and month3 - month2 = 1 month
mthIndices = mthIndices[mthIndices$Var2- mthIndices$Var1==1 & mthIndices$Var3 - mthIndices$Var2==1,]
rownames(mthIndices) = NULL


mthIndices
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
#1     1    2    3
#2     2    3    4
#3     3    4    5
#4     4    5    6
#5     5    6    7
#6     6    7    8
#7     7    8    9
#8     8    9   10
#9     9   10   11
#10   10   11   12
```

**PCA:**

```
#for each row of mthIndices i.e. JFM, FMA,..., OND

pcaDF = do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(mthIndices),function(x) {

#monthly indices of data
dataIndices = month(as.Date(index(managers)))

#subset dataset for current scheme 
DF = managers[dataIndices %in% mthIndices[x,],]

#perform calculations
subDF = DF[complete.cases(DF),]

pcaObj = princomp(subDF)


#JFM,FMA names
monthNames = paste0(month.name[unlist(mthIndices[x,])],collapse=",")

#return dataset of interest i.e. loadings,sdev etc.
returnValue = data.frame(monthNames,t(pcaObj$center),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

return(returnValue)

}))
```

**Output:**

```
pcaDF

#                   monthNames         HAM1         HAM2          HAM3         HAM4         HAM5
#1      January,February,March  0.007713333  0.003893333  0.0082866667  0.006993333  0.009606667
#2        February,March,April  0.007480000 -0.001293333  0.0067266667  0.013273333  0.001713333
#3             March,April,May  0.008786667  0.003060000  0.0061933333  0.022533333  0.002406667
#4              April,May,June  0.008780000  0.001313333 -0.0003266667  0.017213333  0.003466667
#5               May,June,July  0.001673333  0.002913333 -0.0028600000  0.004600000 -0.005126667
#6            June,July,August  0.003200000  0.001266667 -0.0018600000 -0.002660000 -0.001426667
#7       July,August,September -0.003768750  0.002431250 -0.0005500000 -0.019675000  0.000862500
#8    August,September,October  0.006188235  0.001494118  0.0045352941 -0.005235294  0.001564706
#9  September,October,November  0.014194444  0.005900000  0.0109388889  0.021077778  0.004483333
#10  October,November,December  0.024327778  0.006222222  0.0122055556  0.047911111  0.006538889
#           HAM6 EDHEC.LS.EQ      SP500.TR     US.10Y.TR    US.3m.TR
#1  0.0148133333 0.007140000  0.0006703333 -0.0001306667 0.001709333
#2  0.0082466667 0.004173333  0.0020553333 -0.0013560000 0.001791333
#3  0.0060266667 0.003980000  0.0059673333  0.0002586667 0.001941333
#4  0.0008066667 0.002280000  0.0017626667  0.0057260000 0.001931333
#5  0.0002200000 0.000480000 -0.0016106667  0.0038946667 0.001976000
#6  0.0022933333 0.002140000 -0.0027520000  0.0073233333 0.002021333
#7  0.0031187500 0.001481250 -0.0100375000  0.0120693750 0.002271250
#8  0.0089352941 0.006135294  0.0049647059  0.0123805882 0.002295294
#9  0.0152000000 0.010594444  0.0156222222  0.0022616667 0.002325556
#10 0.0235166667 0.014944444  0.0270794444 -0.0017172222 0.002203333
```